# Confirm form resubmission behaviour on refresh while using POST

Tags: php, mysql

In case of POST method,parameters are not stored in the Browser History.
Then on form resubmission how the previous/redundant data is again inserted to the database?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
if($request_method=='POST')
{
$eventtype=$_POST['event-type'];
$eventname=$_POST['eventname'];
$teamA=$_POST['A-team'];
$teamB=$_POST['B-team'];
$gender=$_POST['gender'];
$s=$_POST['date'];

$time=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($s));
$matchtype=$_POST['match-type'];
$venue=$_POST['venue'];

$query= "INSERT INTO `fixtures` (`eventname`,`event-type`,`A-team`,`B-team`,`Gender`,`time`,`match-type`,`venue`) VALUES ('$eventname','$eventtype','$teamA','$teamB','$gender','$time','$matchtype','$venue');";
$res = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
if($res)
    echo 'inserted';
    else
        echo 'not inserted';
mysqli_close($connection);

}
}
```

Comment: "In case of POST method,parameters are not stored in the Browser History." — Yes they are. Even if the browser doesn't provide a UI to allow the user to inspect them, they are still stored.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need "if($request_method=='POST')". The method is defined with $_POST.

I make my MySQL Codes without the last semicolon:

```
$query= "INSERT INTO `fixtures` (`eventname`,`event-type`,`A-team`,`B-team`,`Gender`,`time`,`match-type`,`venue`) VALUES ('$eventname','$eventtype','$teamA','$teamB','$gender','$time','$matchtype','$venue')";
```

Edit:
In the HTML:

In the PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) {

$myinputname = $_POST['myinputname']
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Norman but actually the code was just for reference my question is about the POST method and confirm resubmission.So plz help me with that.